# Right click shows black box in Chrome on Linux

Tags: google-chrome

I've been using chrome for about a year steady.  About a month back two weird behaviors happened.  When I right click anywhere I get a black box.  If I remember what the choices are in the box, I can use the arrow keys to select and it works.

The second problem is that when I mouse over anything, I don't get the tool tip text, I get some graphic display that looks like a very tiny version of some distorted text or graphics

Version 44.0.2403.125, 
lubuntu

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Menu> Settings> Show Advanced Settings > System menu > 
Use hardware acceleration when available: turn it off

Comment: Add the same with Chrome Version 44.0.2403.130 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04, solved the problem. This bug sometimes made crash my computer...

Comment: In case, a black box appears on clicking the three bars on top right to access the Settings page, access that page using `chrome://settings`

Comment: is there any decent explanation why this is happening? because i used to use the hardware acceleration feature all the time, and this suddenly started to happen

Comment: I'm curious as to why this occurs as well, especially seeing as this issue is evidently at least 8 years old